# Creating mulitdimensional array from csv list

Tags: php, csv, multidimensional-array

I think this is a beginner's question..
I cannot find an example of this, although that may reflect that I am too naive to know what to search for..

If I have a string (the comma could be any other character):

```
58732,hc_p0d
58737,hc_p4
58742,hc_p4a
```

(new lines use "\r\n")

How can I split this into a multidimensional array (2X3 in this case, but the number of rows can vary.)

I think is the form I would want (But please suggest better ways if this is not appropriate!):

```
array(
    array(58732,hc_p0d),
    array(58737,hc_p4),
    array(58742,hc_p4a),
)
```

The nearest I have got is  using $vars = explode("\r\n",$input);
With vars looking like this (in cakephp):

```
(int) 0 => '58732,hc_p0d',
(int) 1 => '58737,hc_p4',
(int) 2 => '58742,hc_p4a',
(int) 3 => '58747,hc_p4b',
```

Thanks

Comment: Start with [fgetcsv()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) or better yet [str_getcsv()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert CSV data to array format you can do it in this way

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('data.csv'));
```

Check this reference for further explanation
http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

And if it is not from file but a string containing CSV data you can do it like

```
$data = $csv_data;
$csv_data_rows = explode('\r\n',$data);
$final_array = array();
foreach($csv_data_rows as $key => $value){
$final_array[$key] = explode(',',$value);
}

return $final_array;
```

Comment: The string is not from a file, it is being passed as a string variable.. does that make a difference?  i am getting message from array_map that the my string needs to be an array, not a string..

Comment: Tarun - many thanks for this, but the output is not quite right:

Comment: [
 (int) 0 => [
  (int) 0 => '58732',
  (int) 1 => 'hc_p0d
58737',
  (int) 2 => 'hc_p4
58742',
  (int) 3 => 'hc_p4a
58747',
  (int) 4 => 'hc_p4b
58752',
  (int) 5 => 'hc_p4c
58757',
  (int) 6 => 'hc_p4d
'
 ]

Comment: You can see the first row has been split over rows 1 and 2 (sorry array element, not row).  and then the Numeric value is not split from the string value (string is from row 1 and number from row 2 in the input string..

Comment: It looks like CSV string is not properly created as while exploding the string with `'\r\n'` not giving desired results.

Comment: I agree that this must be to do with the string.  The string is created by appending the numeric value and the text value to a textarea, followed by appending "\r\n" so that the items appear as a list in the text area.  The value of the text area is then used to create  the input string we are looking at.  The example at the top shows what the string looks like...